# Does Quartz scheduler have inclusion calendars

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Does Quartz scheduler have inclusion calendars? I see that there exclusion calendars but I do not see anything about inclusion calendars.  I would like to be able to select days from calendar and run jobs on those days.  There is not necessarily a pattern to the dates.  How can I do this in Quartz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quartz Calendar only defines inclusions. Here is the interface:

```
public interface Calendar {

  public boolean isTimeIncluded(long timeStamp);

  public long getNextIncludedTime(long timeStamp);

}
```

Some implementations are used for defining exclusions but other support inclusions. Take a look at [DailyCalendar](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/impl/calendar/DailyCalendar.html) and its [invertTimeRange](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/impl/calendar/DailyCalendar.html#setInvertTimeRange(boolean)) property.

Since you mention that you want to include only specific days on your calendar, I suspect you might have to implement your own calendar. Check out [BaseCalendar](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/index.html?org/quartz/impl/calendar/BaseCalendar.html) which should be a great starting point.

If you're lazy, you might be able to inherit [HolidayCalendar](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz/1.8.2/org/quartz/impl/calendar/HolidayCalendar.java) and simply change `isTimeIncluded` to

```
@Override
public boolean isTimeIncluded(long timeStamp) {
    if (super.isTimeIncluded(timeStamp) == false) {
        return false;
    }

    Date lookFor = getStartOfDayJavaCalendar(timeStamp).getTime();

    return dates.contains(lookFor); // <-- HERE we remove the bang (!)
}
```

Defining your calendar should be pretty simple. Keep in mind that it needs to be `Serializable`!

Check out the [Quartz Tutorial](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-04.html) for more info.

Comment: If this answered your question, please accept this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers @user3375401